Autler Townes Splitting Red Vs Blue Detuned
In Foot's atomic physics on page 144 he derives the eigenenergies of dressed states of a two=level atom to be
$$\lambda_{\pm}=\pm\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\delta^{2}+\Omega^{2}}$$
from Hamiltonian matrix
$$\hat{H}=\begin{pmatrix} 
\delta/2 & \Omega/2 \\ 
\Omega/2 & -\delta/2 
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
As far as i can tell, for any value of $\delta$ the value $\lambda_{+}-\lambda_{-}=2\lambda_{+}$ will increase with $\Omega$. My confusion comes from the plot on the following page:

This clearly shows that for blue detuning (positive $\delta$) the energy levels get closer together as the coherent field increases.
Can anyone help me work out what i've missed here? Clearly i'm misinterpreting something.
